# Start VirtualBox Headless VM On Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, boot

I am running two VirtualBox headless VMs on an Ubuntu 12.04 host.  I would like these VMs to start automatically when the system boots.

I have two crontab entries set like this (under the user which owns the VMs):

```
@reboot /usr/bin/vboxheadless -startvm io
@reboot /usr/bin/vboxheadless -startvm pbx
```

But it seems that doesn't do the trick.  If I run the command directly from the terminal, the machines start up without a hitch, but I can't seem to get them to start once the system starts.  I'm thinking maybe the crontab is running before the VirtualBox program/library is loaded.

How do I start these VMs automatically?

Answer (score 7):

This is what I use. It starts the VMs on boot and saves their state on shutdown/reboot

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       vmboot
# Required-Start: vboxdrv
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: Stop/Start VMs on System shutdown
### END INIT INFO

VBOXUSER=vboxuser
SU="sudo -H -u $VBOXUSER"
VBOXMANAGE=/usr/bin/VBoxManage
VBOXHEADLESS=/usr/bin/VBoxHeadless
RUNNINGVMS=$($SU $VBOXMANAGE --nologo list runningvms | sed -e 's/^".*".*{\(.*\)}/\1/')
ALLVMS=$($SU $VBOXMANAGE --nologo list vms | sed -e 's/^".*".*{\(.*\)}/\1/')

case $1 in
stop)
if [[ -n $RUNNINGVMS ]]; then
echo "Saving the state of all running VMs..."
for v in $RUNNINGVMS; do
    $SU $VBOXMANAGE --nologo controlvm $v savestate
done
fi
;;
start)
for v in $ALLVMS; do
if [[ -n $($SU $VBOXMANAGE --nologo showvminfo $v | grep saved) ]]; then
    echo "Restoring VMs..." && $SU $VBOXHEADLESS -s $v & > /dev/null
fi
done
;;
*)
echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vmboot start | stop"; exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Just save it in /etc/init.d. I named mine vbox. Run `update-rc.d <script name> defaults` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're logged in with an account other than root when you start the VMs manually, while `cron` runs as root and thus doesn't know about your VMs. You can check that by running the command

```
sudo /usr/bin/vboxheadless -startvm io
```

If you get an error

```
Invalid machine name or UUID!
```

the VM is not registered with the root account. In that case create a shell script to run the commands under your account and schedule that script with `cron`:

```
#!/bin/sh

USERNAME=...

su -c "/usr/bin/vboxheadless -startvm io" - $USERNAME
su -c "/usr/bin/vboxheadless -startvm pbx" - $USERNAME
```

Comment: The cronjob is running as the user which the VMs are registered under.

Comment: Then check `/.../VMNAME/Logs/VBox.log`.

Comment: The log file doesn't seem to show anything regarding the VM not starting up.  All iterations of the log show a successful VM start.  However I believe it might have something to do with the cron running before virtualbox has started up.

Comment: Next step would be to check `/var/log/syslog` and the output of `dmesg`.

Answer (score 0):

A secondary option also if your MB/CPU support hardware visualization is ProxMox.
Its a self contained install of Linux, KVM and a web interface. it has much better performance over virtualbox as it runs at a kernel level and instead of "virtual" only drives like virtualbox uses you can actually connect a guest under KVM to a physical drive which uses a LOT less disk Io.

Quick check if your system supports hardware visualization:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```